# time exceeded exception in prolog, get last value before interupt

Tags: time, prolog, try-catch

i have predicate that counts factorial for number N, but when time exceeded 1 sec, it is interupted:

```
factorial( 0, 1 ).
factorial( N, Value ) :-
    N > 0,
    Prev is N - 1,
    factorial( Prev, Prevfact ),
    Value is Prevfact * N.

fact(N,V) :-
catch(call_with_time_limit(1, factorial(N,V)  ),
    time_limit_exceeded,
    write('time exceeded!')).
```

How can i get the last value of V just before factorial is interupted ?

thanks

Comment: use a global variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no last value for `V` in your code just before the calculation is interrupted - it will be uninstantiated yet. And if it is instantiated, then the calculation has ended and there was no interruption.

If you want to find out the biggest factorial you can calculate in one second, you will have to save it through some mechanism which is not destroyed by backtracking (because `catch/3` backtracks).

But the way your code is written, you won't have *any* value to save until half way through the calculation. And if it would take, say, 3 seconds total, it means you won't have any value to save during its first 1.5 seconds of run:

```
factorial( 0, 1 ).
factorial( N, Value ) :-
    N > 0,
    Prev is N - 1,
    factorial( Prev, Prevfact ),
    % here - save the value of Prevfact, e.g. with nb_setval/2
    Value is Prevfact * N.
```

That is because it calculates its factorials on the way back up from the depths of the recursion.

To make it calculate some values immediately, change it to use an accumulator:

```
factorial(N,F):- factorial(N,1,1,F).
factorial(N,A,K,F):- K>N -> F=A ; 
  A2 is A*K, K2 is K+1,   % save (A2,K) here
  factorial(N,A2,K2,F).
```